# Django pdf question

Tags: django, url, pdf, view, reportlab

I Want to know if there is a way I could generate a whole html document into a pdf file. I have already report lab and have done some examples with strings before in the past. But I want to know if there is a way how to change a template into some output which is a pdf file.

Comment: Hi, I have created a django app just for that : Django-pdf-generator. Maybe you can give it a try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Pisa/XHTML2PDF](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/). I did some experiments with it a couple of years back but switched to pure ReportLab when it proved inadequate. It may fit your needs better than it did mine.

Comment: I have heard of Pisa before but did not really like it. Is there a way to do it with reportlab.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to convert HTML to PDF using ReportLab alone.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually, the converter however lives in the paid version of ReportLab which is packages under the name rlextra. The converter is called html2rml so it would give you an RML string back which then you need to use rml2pdf to use it. It might work with the free RML implementation but you better post your question to the reportlab mailing list.